# A problem with deriving posterior of particle filter

Tags: posterior, particle-filter

At the normal particle filter, there is an equation to deriving posterior $p(x_{0:k}|z_{1:k})$. In the [article](http://moodle.technion.ac.il/pluginfile.php/179706/mod_resource/content/0/2010/particle-filters1.pdf) ,equation 45 , it says that:

$p(x_{0:k}|z_{1:k})=\frac{p(z_k|x_k)p(x_k|x_{k-1})}{p(z_k|z_{1:k-1})}p(x_{0:k-1}|z_{1:k-1})$

and in equation 46, it says this equation is proportional to

${p(z_k|x_k)p(x_k|x_{k-1})}p(x_{0:k-1}|z_{1:k-1})$

therefore, the denominator $p(z_k|z_{1:k-1})$ is constant, why?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of your newer question about the same issue in Kalman filtering, where you now have received an answer.

Comment: I will flag it duplicated or delete it